# FuelPHP and Smarty - Variables not working

Tags: php, smarty, fuelphp

Not sure if Smarty is even loading but its showing {$title} and {$username} directly on the page and not using what's set as the variable.

I added into composer.json

> "smarty/smarty": "*"

I run `php composer.phar update` and also `install`:

I'm loading in the config.php file the parser as per

```
'packages'  => array(
  'orm',
  'auth',
  'parser',
),
```

In my controller dashboard.php

```
public function action_index()
    {
        $data = [
        'bodyclass' => "dashboard",
        'title' => "Dashboard",
        'username' => "James"
    ];
        $view = Response::forge(View::forge('dashboard/index.tpl', $data));

        $this->template->subnav = array('dashboard'=> 'active' );
        $this->template->content = $view;
    }
```

and in my index.tpl file I have

> {$title} {$username}

It's just for testing, however does not seem to be working.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, just seen it. Apart from the fact that you shouldn't wrap the View into a Response, I don't see anything immediately wrong. You are sure the double brace is used as delimiter, and not the single brace (which is default, see the parser.php config file in the parser package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FuelPHP's [Parser](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/parser/intro.html) package handles the rendering of views using template engines.

As you've already done, you must first enable the Parser package in `fuel/app/config.php` by making sure the parser package is added to `always_load`

```
'always_load' => array(
    'packages' => array(
        'parser',
    ),
),
```

Parser uses the file's extension to determine which parser engine to use.  In your case your file, `dashboard/index.tpl` uses a typical smarty extension `.tpl`, however FuelPHP doesn't have a template registered for that extension.

FuelPHP uses `.smarty` by default.

So, you have 2 options.

1. Change your template's file extension, adhering to the FuelPHP default
2. Change FuelPHP's configuration to use Smarty for .tpl files

Fortunately both are easy.  If you choose to go with option 2, check out the [default configuration definition](https://github.com/fuel/parser/blob/262378f93def45ffd7cdde0c1ff6dee873f5979e/config/parser.php#L38).

You can override the defaults using a config file located at `fuel/app/config/parser.php`

```
return array(

    // Overrides default smarty extension
    'extensions' => array(
        'tpl' => 'View_Smarty',
    )
);
```